# How to add a row to a Pandas dataframe with the same value all the way down

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to add a new row/series to my dataframe with all values set to 'dummy'.

```
df['new_col'] = pd.Series(data='dummy')
```

This does add a new column, but none of the values are populated. I want to get the data to be dummy all the way down for however many rows are already in the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try

```
df['new_col'] = 'dummy'
```